# What's the use of `this` in this example?

Tags: javascript

I'm using a module to detect when the user is speaking, called `hark`. Here's some of the code:

```
// original source code is taken from:
// https://github.com/SimpleWebRTC/hark
// copyright goes to &yet team
// edited by Muaz Khan for RTCMultiConnection.js
function hark(stream, options) {
    var audioContextType = window.webkitAudioContext || window.AudioContext;

    var harker = this;
    harker.events = {};
    harker.on = function (event, callback) {
        harker.events[event] = callback;
    };

    harker.emit = function () {
        if (harker.events[arguments[0]]) {
            harker.events[arguments[0]](arguments[1], arguments[2], arguments[3], arguments[4]);
        }
    };

    // make it not break in non-supported browsers
    if (!audioContextType) return harker;

    options = options || {};
    // Config
    var smoothing = (options.smoothing || 0.1),
        interval = (options.interval || 50),
        threshold = options.threshold,
        play = options.play,
        history = options.history || 10,
        running = true;
    
    (...)

    return harker;
}
```

What is this line for?

```
var harker = this;
```

When I checked in the debugger, this stores a `Window` object in `harker`. And from what I'm seeing it makes for some unexpected behavior when I call `hark` more than once.

Why not just do `var harker;`?

Full code is here:
https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/hark.js

And here's a demo where it's used:

```
<style>
    html, body {
        margin: 0!important;
        padding: 0!important;
    }

    video {
        width: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<title>Auto Stop RecordRTC on Silence</title>
<h1>Auto Stop RecordRTC on Silence</h1>

<br>
<button id="btn-start-recording">Start Recording</button>
<button id="btn-stop-recording" disabled style="display: none;">Stop Recording</button>

<hr>
<video controls autoplay playsinline></video>

<script src="/RecordRTC.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/hark.js"></script>
<script>
var video = document.querySelector('video');
var h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
var default_h1 = h1.innerHTML;

function captureCamera(callback) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true }).then(function(camera) {
        callback(camera);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        alert('Unable to capture your camera. Please check console logs.');
        console.error(error);
    });
}

function stopRecordingCallback() {
    video.srcObject = null;
    var blob = recorder.getBlob();
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    recorder.camera.stop();
    video.muted = false;
}

var recorder; // globally accessible

document.getElementById('btn-start-recording').onclick = function() {
    this.disabled = true;
    captureCamera(function(camera) {
        video.muted = true;
        video.srcObject = camera;

        recorder = RecordRTC(camera, {
            type: 'video'
        });

        recorder.startRecording();

        var max_seconds = 3;
        var stopped_speaking_timeout;
        var speechEvents = hark(camera, {});

        speechEvents.on('speaking', function() {
            if(recorder.getBlob()) return;

            clearTimeout(stopped_speaking_timeout);

            if(recorder.getState() === 'paused') {
                // recorder.resumeRecording();
            }
            
            h1.innerHTML = default_h1;
        });

        speechEvents.on('stopped_speaking', function() {
            if(recorder.getBlob()) return;

            // recorder.pauseRecording();
            stopped_speaking_timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                document.getElementById('btn-stop-recording').click();
                h1.innerHTML = 'Recording is now stopped.';
            }, max_seconds * 1000);

            
            // just for logging purpose (you ca remove below code)
            var seconds = max_seconds;
            (function looper() {
                h1.innerHTML = 'Recording is going to be stopped in ' + seconds + ' seconds.';
                seconds--;

                if(seconds <= 0) {
                    h1.innerHTML = default_h1;
                    return;
                }

                setTimeout(looper, 1000);
            })();
        });

        // release camera on stopRecording
        recorder.camera = camera;

        document.getElementById('btn-stop-recording').disabled = false;
    });
};

document.getElementById('btn-stop-recording').onclick = function() {
    this.disabled = true;
    recorder.stopRecording(stopRecordingCallback);
};
</script>

<footer style="margin-top: 20px;"><small id="send-message"></small></footer>
<script src="https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/common.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's used inside the callback functions, for instance `harker.events[event] = callback;` needs the outer `this`, since the inner `this` points to the callback function itself.

Comment: `this` is a js operator/keyword that binds the scope to the context of the block where it's defined. Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and [here](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html)

Answer (score 3):

The pattern of assigning the value of `this` to a variable is something you can read more about by searching for `this that pattern` (or `self = this` ) for example, since that's a common name for the variable for "saving" a reference to this.

The reason for doing that is that `this` changes depending on the context of functions. If you assign `this` at a specific scope you can pass that along to other functions - since they wouldn't be able to use `this`, since `this` might mean something completely different to them.